# Copy file in Python using shutil giving TypeError

Tags: python

I'm getting errors in python 2.6 trying to create a copy of a file I recently created and closed:

```
#Create a new file
outfile = open(iOutFilePath, 'w')
outfile.write('some stuff\n')
outfile.close()

#Now create a new copy of this file:
dst="test.xml"
shutil.copy(outfile, dst)
```

I'm getting an error which normally happens if (from my understanding and looking at similar questions here) happens if you try to write to the same file

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

The destination file definitely does not exist.
What am I missing?

Comment: use shutil.copy(iOutFilePath, dst) with filename. you are using fileobject which is closed

Comment: That fixed it, thanks.